# Java threadpool oversubscription

Tags: java, threadpool

I have mainly CPU intensive operation which is running on a thread pool. 
Operation however has certain amount of waiting foe external events which doesn't happen uniformly in time.
Since in Java, as far as I know, there is not a thread pool implementation which automatically sizes its number of threads based on observed task throughput (as in Microsoft's CLR 4), is there at least a way to manually tell to thread pool to increase its size when a blocking operation starts and to decrease when it ends?

For example with 8 cores, pool size is 8. 
  If operation is 100% CPU bound, just use this fixed pool.
  If there is some blocking operation, one should be able to do this:

```
pool.increase();
waitForSpecialKeyPress();
pool.decrease();
```

Here is how it is being done in Microsoft's C++ Async library: [Use Oversubscription to Offset Latency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd984042.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java 7's ForkJoinPool has a [ManagedBlocker](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.ManagedBlocker.html), which can be used to keep the pool informed about blocked threads, so that it can schedule more threads if necessary.

EDIT: I forgot to mention, the classes are also available for Java 6 as [jsr166y](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/concurrency-interest/).

Answer (score 4):

You could extend `ThreadPoolExecutor` to add your own `increase()` and `decrease()` functions, which do simple `setMaximumPoolSize(getMaximumPoolSize() +/- 1)`.

Make sure to synchronize the methods, to make sure you don't mess up the pool size by accident.